# Make the footer stay at bottom of the page without content getting clipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer

I am calculating the window height and other elements height and making the footer stay at bottom. I tried with JavaScript but the footer is only taking the header element height and aligning the footer just below the header. I wanted to make the footer stay at bottom with the help of JavaScript. Using position as fixed in css clips the content. I want the footer to grow as and when the content grows. Thats the reason i am trying to achieve this in JavaScript or JQuery and not pure CSS.

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/qmjdfkxh/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function pageheight() {
debugger
  var ContainerMinHeight = ($(window).height()) - (($("header").height()) + ($("footer").height() + 27));
  $("body").css("min-height", ContainerMinHeight);
}
pageheight();;
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u24nctj7/

Comment: Don't use JS for styling. CSS is more than capable of achieveing this. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: I am not looking for a position fixed approach. I want the footer to move as and when i resize my browser.

Comment: Position fixed will remain fixed and the content will be hidden when the content grows. I dont want that to happen. I want the footer to grow as and when the content is added.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the question. I suppose this shouldnt be a duplicate as i am not asking the solution in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed positioning, don't really need to use jquery at all

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by css:

```
position: fixed
```

Reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try with css

> position: fixed

Apply this css at the parent div

Comment: This will clip the content when the content grows.

Answer (score -1):

You can do with CSS only. No need to use Js or Jquery.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer

Comment: This will clip the content when the content grows.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use CSS with position fixed. Example CSS rules:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use fixed position in css. You also have to take care that the html and the body element take 100% of the windows height.